# Backward compatibility Material Design

Tags: android, compatibility, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

As Google says in [this page](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html), Material Theme is only available on Android L Developer Preview.
But how can these apps work on previous version of Android L?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.borggren.notes

http://officialandroid.blogspot.it/2014/10/a-new-look-for-google-play-newsstand.html

There are other apps.

Do they use some components similar to material design?

Don't they use the "android:Theme.Material"?

Or is there a way to use Material Theme on previous versions (and I am the only one who doesn't know how to do this)?

Comment: In the second case, that is a Google app, and so Google can do whatever Google wants.

Comment: Ok. I know. I agree. But in the first case?

Comment: Wait for the support lib to be updated for Material.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120764/android-material-design-on-kitkat-and-lower-devices/26121535#26121535

Answer (score 1):

I think they are using the components not the theme itself. If you try to give this theme as your overall theme in studio without the minSDK =21 it gives you an error. They are trying to emulate the material design.

For example if you want the floating action bar you can use this project. https://github.com/FaizMalkani/FloatingActionButton

I guess he uses frame layout to emulate that button on the lower right corner. Have a look!!